# To show a matrix $A=I$ if all eigen values are $1$ and the set $\{A^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be bounded

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with all eigenvalues equal to $1$. Suppose the set $\{A^k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be bounded, then show that $A\equiv I$.

I tried from spectral radius formuale $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to 0}A^n=0\iff
\rho(A)<1$.

Here $\rho(A)=1$ but then I am lost, please give me hint. Thanks

Comment: Do you know about jordan normal form?

Comment: I think it is follows from Jordan form of such matrices.

Comment: You should change the notation of the exponent: $n$ is the size of the matrix $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By what is given, $N:=A-I$ is nilpotent. Assume $N\ne 0$. Then we can find $v$ with $Nv\ne 0$ and $N^2v=0$. Writing $w=Nv$ we find by induction that $A^k v= v+kw$. As the sequence $v+kw$ is unbounded we conclude that $A^k$ is also unbounded, contradiction.

Comment: Why $N^2v=0$?....

Answer (score 2):

Hint: let $n=2$. The Jordan form of such matrix if $A\neq I$ is 
\begin{equation}
J_A=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation}
Clearly its power series is not bounded.